# Angularjs MMMM dd, yyyy ng-pattern returns error

Tags: angularjs, regex

I have a field that is set for date to be entered as a value but AngularJs returns error on the field whenever I enter a date.

This is how the pattern looks

```
ng-pattern='/^(?:(((Jan(uary)?|Ma(r(ch)?|y)|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Oct(ober)?|Dec(ember)?)\ 31)|((Jan(uary)?|Ma(r(ch)?|y)|Apr(il)?|Ju((ly?)|(ne?))|Aug(ust)?|Oct(ober)?|(Sept|Nov|Dec)(ember)?)\ (0?[1-9]|([12]\d)|30))|(Feb(ruary)?\ (0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]|(29(?=,\ ((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))))))\,\ ((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))/'
```

I've tested the patter on **regexr** and it's working. The date I'm testing with is **June 30, 2016**

Comment: Your regex looks terrible despite it compiles well, you can look at [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/zXqxzmY0J6ClQoaP). I would use a different way to test it, you could use a method to validate the date and pass it to ng-pattern like `ng-pattern='myValidation()'`

Comment: Why do you allow matching "Mary" (see `Ma(r(ch)?|y)`)?

Answer (score 0):

I went over your regex (it's very well thought out), and ended up re-writing it based off your concepts.

Here's what I ended up with:

```
((Jan(uary)?|Mar(ch)?|July?|Aug(ust)?|Oct(ober)?|Dec(ember)?) 31|(Jan(uary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|July?|June?|Aug(ust)?|Oct(ober)?|Sep|(Sept|Nov|Dec)(ember)?) (0?[1-9]|([12]\d)|30)|Feb(ruary)? (0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]|29(?=, ((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))), (1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}
```

Here's an example: https://regex101.com/r/gS0xB4/1

And here it is broken up a little:

```
( // Begin get month and a day
    (Jan(uary)?|Mar(ch)?|July?|Aug(ust)?|Oct(ober)?|Dec(ember)?) 31 // Months with 31 days, and a 31
    | // OR
    (Jan(uary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|July?|June?|Aug(ust)?|Oct(ober)?|Sep|(Sept|Nov|Dec)(ember)?) // Every month but Feb, and...
    (0?[1-9]|([12]\d)|30) // A number from 1-30, optionally padded to 2 digits
    | // OR
    Feb(ruary)? // Feburary, and...
        (0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8] // A number from 1-28, optionally padded to 2 digits
        | // OR
        29(?=, ( // A 29, IF it is followed by a comma and...
            (1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26]) // A year which is a multiple of 4, but not a multiple of 100
            | // OR
            (16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00) // A year which is a multiple of 400
        ) // End 29 conditional
    ) // End Feb
) // End month and day
, (1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2} // A comma, and a year between 1600 and 9999
```

I don't have any capturing groups for breaking it up, since I was just trying to get it to match - but they should be fairly easy to add in. I also removed all the escapes, so you might have to add them back in if the engine demands them.